# Insert multiple image names into same database field, separated by comma

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

I have this script:

UPLOAD MULTIPLE FILES -  PIECE OF CODE

```
foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {    

    if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
    } 

    else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$f], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $uniq_name = uniqid() . '.' .$ext;
        $dest = $path . $uniq_name; //FULL DESTINATION
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $dest)) {
            $count++;   
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to insert into my mysql database all the photo names, in the PHOTOS field, separated by a comma.

When I'm writing the 2 lines code:

```
$a = "INSERT INTO dbu.dbu_data(photos) VALUES ('$uniq_name')";
mysql_query($a);
```

IT INSERTS A TABLE ROW FOR EACH PHOTO THAT WAS UPLOADED AND I DON'T WANT THAT.

Comment: don't. you do NOT store multiple pieces of independent data in a single field. Doing that negates the primary reason for using a relational database. Normalize your tables and put each file's information into a separate record in a child table.

Comment: And you do *not* type entire sentences in uppercase.

Comment: ok, any other solution please.

Answer (score 1):

```
$delimiter = ",";
$str = '';

foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {

    if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {

        // surely your move logic needs to go here

    } else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$f], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $uniq_name = uniqid() . '.' .$ext;
        $dest = $path . $uniq_name; //FULL DESTINATION
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $dest)) {
            $count++;

            if (strlen($str)) {
                $str .= $delimiter;
            }

            $str .= $dest;

        }
    }

}

if (strlen($str)){

    $a = "INSERT INTO dbu.dbu_data(photos) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($str) . "')";
    mysql_query($a);

}
```

Comment: It only inserts the last picture name in the field photos. Not all the pic names, just the last :(

Comment: if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0)  you sure this logic is right? and have you verified all the images get moved correctly?

Comment: and does your input field look something like <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple> .. notice the []

Comment: see above where i wrote this .. // surely your move logic needs to go here

Comment: YES YES YES - everything works now!! Thanks you so much MYTE!

Comment: It also works without mysql_real_escape_string, just $str .. Thank you anyway!